# Let $a,b,c=1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\0 & d\end{bmatrix}$. Is $\{A^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $a,b,c=1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\0 & d\end{bmatrix}$. 
Is $\{A^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a group?

I'm not really sure how to approach this question. If you take $A^3$ you get the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

$3 \notin \mathbb{Z}_3$. Is this enough to show that $A^n$is not a group or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: You are mistaken: $3=0$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a group. Show that the multiplication is closed (you have done this, I think), and then show that every element has an inverse. So it is a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/3)$.